# Django REST Framework Serializer returning object instead of data

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I am writing a simple database for the condo I live in which has a list of people, units, unit type (home vs parking space), and unitholder (join table for many-to-many relationship between a person and a unit) - one person can be the owner of a unit type of "home" while renting a parking space.

This is my model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=20)

class UnitType(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Unit(models.Model):
    unit_number = models.IntegerField(null=False, unique=True)
    unit_type = models.ForeignKey(UnitType, null=False)
    unitholders = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='UnitHolder')

class UnitHolderType(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class UnitHolder(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
    unitholder_type = models.ForeignKey(UnitHolderType)
```

This is my view:

```
class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer

class UnitHolderTypeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UnitHolderType.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UnitHolderTypeSerializer

class UnitViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Unit.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UnitSerializer

class UnitHolderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UnitHolder.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UnitHolderSerializer

class UnitTypeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UnitType.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UnitTypeSerializer
```

This is my serializer:

```
class UnitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    unit_type = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=UnitType.objects.all(), slug_field='description'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = ('unit_number', 'unit_type', 'unitholders')

class UnitTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UnitType

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

class UnitHolderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    person = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, read_only=True)
    unit = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UnitHolder
        fields = ('person', 'unit', 'unitholder_type')

class UnitHolderTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UnitHolderType
```

The problem:

When I query the /units endpoint like the following:

```
u = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/units').json()
```

My response looks like this:

```
[{'unit_type': 'Home', 'unit_number': 614, 'unitholders': [1]}]
```

What I want back is something like this:

```
[
    {
        'unit_type': 'Home', 
        'unit_number': 614, 
        'unitholders': [
            {
                'id: 1,
                'first_name': 'myfirstname',
                'last_name': 'mylastname',
                'unitholder_type': 'renter'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm pretty sure my problem is in my UnitSerializer but I am brand new to DRF and read the through the documentation but still can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

An easy solution would be using [`depth`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) option:

```
class UnitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    unit_type = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=UnitType.objects.all(), slug_field='description'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = ('unit_number', 'unit_type', 'unitholders')
        depth = 1
```

This will serialize all nested relations 1 level deep. If you want to have fine control over how each nested field gets serialized, you can list their serializers explicitly:

```
class UnitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    unit_type = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=UnitType.objects.all(), slug_field='description'
    )
    unitholders = UnitHolderSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = ('unit_number', 'unit_type', 'unitholders')
```

Also as a side note, you need to look into modifying your querysets inside views to [prefetch related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/optimization/#retrieve-everything-at-once-if-you-know-you-will-need-it), otherwise you will destroy the app performance very quickly (using something like [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) for monitoring generated queries is very convenient):

```
class UnitViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Unit.objects.all().select_related('unit_type').prefetch_related('unitholders')
    serializer_class = UnitSerializer
```

Comment: thank you! this is all very helpful. depth = 1 worked for me but listing the serializer explicitly through errors. I will try to work those out myself :)

Comment: I just realized that "'unitholder_type': 'renter'" is not being returned. unitholder type is being held in a join table associating 'Unit' and 'Person'. I'd like to return not only the unit associated with the person, but also the association type which is held in the join itself.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you must doing somethings so:

```
class UnitHolderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UnitHolder.objects.all()
    unitholders = UnitHolderSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
```

[Django rest framework serializing many to many field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182092/django-rest-framework-serializing-many-to-many-field)

Comment: hmm. thanks. I just added that to my view but it had no effect. querying that endpoint still returns:

    [{'unit_type': 'Home', 'unit_number': 614, 'unitholders': [1]}]