# Django Rest framework Serialize many to many field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to serialise a json payload that has a field with an array, the `.is_valid()` check is returning true but I am getting `KeyError: 'passengers'` when I try to do this `serializer.data['passengers']` but the other fields work fine (such as booking_number and status).

This is the response.data I am passing to the seralizer:

```
{'booking_number': 2839, 'passengers': [{'first_name': 'Jack', 'surname': 'Smith', 'email': 'smith@mail.com', 'phone_number': '1234'}], 'status': 'ON_HOLD'}
```

My seralizers:

```
class PassengerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Passenger



class FindBus(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    passengers = PassengerSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ('booking_number', 'passengers', 'status')
```

My models:

```
class Passenger(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)                                    
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=25)                                       
    email = models.EmailField()                                                     
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12) 


class Booking(models.Model):
    booking_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)                                                                                           
    passenger = models.ManyToManyField(Passenger)                                   
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10)                                        
    hold_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Any advise on how to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Btw I was following this: [Django rest framework serializing many to many field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182092/django-rest-framework-serializing-many-to-many-field)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to de-serialize fields, you should not use `read_only=True`:

```
class FindBus(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    passengers = PassengerSerializer(many=True)
    ...
```

Note that this won't be enough for saving m2m relationships: as explained in [Writable nested serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers), you'll also need to define `create()` and/or `update()` methods on your serializer:

```
class FindBus(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    passengers = PassengerSerializer(many=True)
    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...

    def update(self, validated_data):
        ...
```

The reason for the need of the `create`/`update` is that you have to decide whether the passenger details that you receive refer to existing objects or need to be created.

You might also need to add `fields = ('__all__',)` (or specify the fields you're interested in) to your `PassengerSerializer`:

```
class PassengerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Passenger
        fields = ('__all__',)
```

Comment: Adding fields = ('__all__') and removing the read only did the trick. Thanks for the additional information.