# Django Rest Framework get many-to-many relation showing in API

Tags: django-rest-framework

My little podcast backend has some models, one of which is Episode. Now there are two new ones for guests (Guest) and topics (Topic) - both of which have a ManyToManyField to Episode. This basically works as intended in the admin. Now I need to bring that to the API.

The detailed Serializer/View for each episode already has some other related data (no many-to-many so far). I also checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182092/django-rest-framework-serializing-many-to-many-field?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but still can't get it it work and think I might miss something.

Here's the essence just for the guest example to keep it dense, topic is literally identical:

Episode Model:

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    number          = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    show            = models.ForeignKey(Show, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    created_at      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
    published_at    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
    updated_at      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
    cover_image     = models.URLField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Guest Model:

```
class Guest(models.Model):
    episodes        = models.ManyToManyField(Episode)
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    twitter         = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serializer:

```
class GuestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Guest
        fields = ('name',)
```

Episode Serializer where it should appear:

```
class EpisodeDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    guest = GuestSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    topic = TopicSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Episode
        fields = (..., 'guest', 'topic')
        depth = 1
```

I have put some data on for guests and topics but I can't get them showing up on the API. I've also tried 'Guest.episodes.through' like I do have it on the admin for Inline Admin Classes but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you post your Episode model as well, since that's the one on which your last serializer is based? And do you have `related_names` set for any of these m2m relationships?

Comment: @souldeux I just did add the Episode model. No, I didn't set `related_names` so far. I read they are optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Episode` model does not have any forward relationships to your `Guest` or `Topic` models. For that reason, your `Episode` serializer should seek to serialize `guest_set` and `topic_set` instead of `guest` and `topic`.

If you specify a related name for those M2M field, you can customize the naming convention here. Right now you have this:

```
class Guest(models.Model):
    episodes = models.ManyToManyField(Episode)
    ...
```

Which means that to get to all the `Guests` associated with a given `Episode` called `ep`, the reverse lookup would be `ep.guest_set.all()`. Define a related name and you can call the middle term whatever you want:

```
class Guest(models.Model):
    episodes = models.ManyToManyField(Episode, related_name='guests')
    ...
```

With this you could use `ep.guests.all()`, and you could update your `Episode` serializer to look for `guests` as opposed to `guest_set`.