# Reverse Serializing Many to Many Relations Causes RecursionError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Following on from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55238403/2075402), I've attempted to reverse serialize objects from a many to many relationship.

Using a serializer method field, I've tried to populate the people that have a person type however this is causing a `RecursionError` from django.

I can see the issue, `PersonA` has `PersonTypeA` who has `PersonA` etc. but I'm not sure how to 'flatten' the returned people to one level.

How can I overcome the recursion error?

Models:

```
class PersonType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

class Person(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    person_types = models.ManyToManyField(PersonType, related_name="people")
```

Serializers:

```
class PersonTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    people = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = PersonType
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_people(self, obj):
        people = obj.people.all()
        response = PersonSerializer(people, many=True).data
        return response

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    person_types = PersonTypeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RecurssionError` is happening not directly because of the models but rather due to the form on how you are trying to serialize your data.

If a `Person` instance is included in a `Type` that contains that `Person` then you enter in a never ending recursion loop where your `serializers` are eternally calling each other.

To solve the error immediately, instead of trying to serialize the QuerySet from your `SerializerMethodField`, return its values instead:

```
class PersonTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    people = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = PersonType
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_people(self, obj):
        people = obj.people.all()
        return people.values()

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
```

Also, I need to point out that you are trying to use [`depth`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) to represent the nested relation. But instead, by creating your own serializer (PersonTypeSerializer), you are overriding it, so you could just have one serializer and let the framework traverse it for you:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Although, that would not return `people` field which is part of your customization. Meaning that `depth` in this case is useless.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your response. Also the insight into the `depth` parameter is really helpful - I wasn't sure if that would help the recursive issue here which is why I tried it in the first place!