# How represent a many to many relationship with django rest framework using Hyperlinking

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have two models in a 'many to many' relationship **Video** and **Genre**. I want to represent them in my API using the Django Rest Framework and with Hyperlinking. I have tried using the the nested relationships solution that I have found over the internet but it brings me an error for the list viewss eg **genres/** and **videos/** as described below.

models.py

```
class VideoGenre(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='genres')
    genres = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='videos')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['video', 'genre']

class Video(models.Model):
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, related_name="videos", blank=True, through='VideoGenre')
    title = serializers.CharField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

class Genre(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
descr = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

serializers.py

```
class GenreSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    videos = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(many=True, view_name="video-detail")

    class Meta:
        model = ku_api_models.Genre
        fields = "__all__"

class VideoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    genres = GenreSerializer(source='genre_set', many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ku_api_models.Video
        fields = "__all__"

class VideoGenreSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    video = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='video.id')
    genre = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='genre.id')

    class Meta:
        model = ku_api_models.VideoGenre
        fields = "__all__"
        unique_together = ['video', 'genre']
```

views.py

```
class VideoDetailView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer
    queryset = Video.objects.all()

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

class VideoListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer
    queryset = Video.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

class GenreListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = GenreSerializer
    queryset = Genre.objects.all()

class GenreDetailtView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = GenreSerializer
    queryset = Genre.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
path('videos/', views.VideoListView.as_view(), name='video-list'),
path('videos/<int:pk>', views.VideoDetailView.as_view(), name='video-detail'),
path('genres/', views.GenreListView.as_view(), name="genre-list"),
path('genres/<int:pk>', views.GenreDetailtView.as_view(), name="genre-detail"),
```

I am getting below exception on the browsable API renderer

> Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /api/genres/
>   Exception Value: relation "ku_api_videogenre" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ..._video"."owner_id" FROM "ku_api_video" INNER JOIN "ku_api_vi...

I have looked into these below links as referred above
[django rest framework serializing many to many field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182092/django-rest-framework-serializing-many-to-many-field?rq=1)

[many to many relationship through an intermidiate model](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164616/django-rest-framework-manytomany-relationship-through-intermediate-model)

[serializing many to many field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182092/django-rest-framework-serializing-many-to-many-field#comment96896172_51177246)

... and tried them but getting the same/almost the same, only different is the relation name that "does not exist"

What am I missing? How to make it right? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to this:
Changes will be in the serializers.py

serializers.py

```
class VideoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    genres = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, read_only=False, view_name='genre-detail', queryset=ku_api_models.Genre.objects.all())


    class Meta:
        model = ku_api_models.Video
        #fields = ('url', 'id', 'datetime_added', 'title', 'video_file', 'owner')
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        genres = validated_data.pop('genres', [])
        video_instance = ku_api_models.Video.objects.create(**validated_data)
        video_instance.genres.set(genres)
        return video_instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        genres = validated_data.pop('genres', [])
        instance.genres.set(genres)
        instance.save()
        return instance

class VideoGenreSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ku_api_models.VideoGenre
        fields = "__all__"

class GenreSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ku_api_models.Genre
        fields = "__all__"
```

Source: [Docs: intermediary-manytomany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)